# Get typename of class when a templated static method is called on a subclass

Tags: c++

The most trivial example of a static method I can think of that makes use of its templated type is this `create()` function.

```
struct Foo {
    template <typename T = Foo>
    static T *create() {
        return new T();
    }
};

struct Bar : Foo {};
struct Baz : Foo {};

int main() {
    Foo::create();
    Bar::create<Bar>();
    // Bar::create(); // Misleading, creates a Foo instead of Bar
    return 0;
}
```

My question is this: Is there anything I can add to the `Foo::create()` static method that automatically detects which class it was called from, to avoid doubly specifying the class name, i.e. `Bar::create()`? I would like to do this without adding a `create()` static method to `Bar`, and `Baz` or any other descendents of `Foo` (because there might be thousands).

Perhaps there's some magic keyword that does this?

```
    template <typename T = this_type>
```

Comment: I'd go the opposite route, and remove the default template argument altogether.

Comment: Is making the `create` function free not acceptable to you? I.e. instead of `Bar::create()` have `create<Bar>()`?

Comment: @StoryTeller That would certainly solve the problem of `Bar::create()` being misleading. It's not a complete solution (if it even exists) since it still requires `Bar::create<Bar>()`.

Comment: Just define another function for Bar::create().

Comment: @Vortico - Well, perhaps I misunderstood your need here. If this is simply about injecting a `create` member without hierarchic relationships, then rustyx got a solution for you.

Comment: @DanM. A major disadvantage with that approach is that it doesn't respect class hierarchy unless I'm mistaken. A subclass of `Foo`, or really any class at all, might need to override the `create()` static method, and as far as I know, template `typename`s are unaware of class hierarchy.

Comment: @Vortico: It's not just "template typename". Base classes are unaware of class hierarchy (CRTP being a clever hack to give a base class a base class of its own). Only the most derived class is aware of the full class hierarchy, and then only towards its bases. Classes aren't aware of their sibliongs either.

Comment: @MSalters I'm unsure what point you're responding to. I was looking for a way to capture the class name `Bar` as something like `this_type` when you call `Bar::create()` in the same way that `bar.func()` exposes `bar` in the method as `this`.

Comment: @Vortico: I responded to your comment "template typenames are unaware of class hierarchy". That's a bit fuzzy statement. If you have `template<typename T>`, you can certainly use `std::is_base_of` on that type `T`.

Answer (score 3):

The best I can think of is CRTP:

```
template<class T>
struct Base {
    static T *create() {
        return new T();
    }
};

struct Foo : public Base<Foo> {};
struct Bar : public Base<Bar> {};
struct Baz : public Base<Baz> {};

int main() {
    Foo* foo = Foo::create();
    Bar* bar = Bar::create();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this technically solves the problem, it requires substantial modification to derived classes, so I'm going to go with "No, there is no way to do this in C++ by modifying just the `Foo::create()` static method."

Comment: Correct, not in the way you want, no. But if you provide more details about what issue you're trying to solve, then maybe someone will come up with a smart alternative solution. BTW you can still have hierarchy in addition to this approach, i.e. have `Bar` derive from `Foo` in addition to `Base<Bar>`. And you can override `create()` in any class, then the default one won't be used.

Comment: I am fine, I'm satisfied with the answer "no". My next-best solution is just to use `Bar::create<Bar>()`. It just looks ugly and I was seeking a language feature which reduced the redundancy and automatically solved nasty issues where you could mismatch class names.

Answer (score 0):

Simple workaround: Add the free function

```
template<typename T>
std::unique_ptr<T> create() {
  return std::unique_ptr<T> { T::template create<T>() };
}
```

You need to repeat T, that's unavoidable, but in this way there's only a single repetition. (It's unavoidable because it's only your application logic which forbids `Foo::create<Bar>`)

Comment: Unfortunately this solution requires modification to every `Foo` descendent, not a single change to `Foo::create()`.

Comment: @Vortico: Not as far as I can see. Try it. `create<Bar>` calls `Bar::create<Bar>`, which finds `Foo::create<T>` and thus instantiates `Foo::create<Bar>`, which indeed calls `new Bar`.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean! I thought you intended for this code to be a static method in each `Foo` subclass rather than a "free function" as you said.

Comment: I suppose in the general case, arguments could be passed through with variadic arguments, so this is a pretty general answer.